# How to add localization to map with intl without widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart

everyone.I using intl to translate.
I have map:

```
Map distanceUnits = <dynamic, String>{
  LengthUnit.mile: S.of(context).mileTranslate,
};
```

It doesn't see the context.
I don't use widgets because it's a separate file with units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function which return map like this

```
 Map<dynamic, String> distanceUnits(BuildContext context) {
    return {
      LengthUnit.mile: S.of(context).mileTranslate,
    };
  }
```